# Criterion for normality of a schematic image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider a projective flat morphism
$$
f\colon X\to Y
$$
between normal varieties. Let's say over the complex numbers. The geometric fibers of $f$ are all irreducible.

I would like a criterion to detect the normality (or the non-normality) of the image of $f$. Maybe in term of the differential of $f$.

Thanks

Comment: If you look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76815/normality-via-resolution-of-singularities/76872#76872 I think it is likely that your hopes will be dashed.  In essence, unless $f$ is flat, it's unlikely that there can be any criteria

Comment: so, let's take $f$ flat. I will edit the question

Comment: In the post you suggested, the author says something like: "if the fibres are reduced and irreducible, then the image of f is normal". Why is this true??

Comment: the point is that "fibers reduced and irreducible then the image is normal' is false.

Comment: here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/76815/normality-via-resolution-of-singularities/214938#214938  there is a comment  "It is obvious that if the fibers are reduced and connected then the variety is normal. In your case the fibers are obviously not reduced. –  Alexander Braverman S"